# add a dataframe column based on grouping by subtitles in R

Tags: r, dataframe

trying to move subtitles to a 3rd column of the following dataframe:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
library(rvest)

url <- "https://resources.companieshouse.gov.uk/sic/"
list <-  read_html(url) %>% 
  html_nodes("table") %>% 
  html_table()

# convert nested list to df
df <- data.frame(Reduce(rbind, list))
```

i'm half way there with getting 21 groups and their names:

```
groups <- cumsum(df[,1] %like% "Section")
group_names <- data.frame(df[df[,1] %like% "Section", 2])
```

but cannot find a dplyr solution that would work with `df %>%  group_by()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are trying to do this :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(group_name = replace(Code, !grepl('Section', Code), NA)) %>%
  tidyr::fill(group_name)

#       Code                                                      Description group_name
#1 Section A                                Agriculture, Forestry and Fishing  Section A
#2     01110 Growing of cereals (except rice), leguminous crops and oil seeds  Section A
#3     01120                                                  Growing of rice  Section A
#4     01130               Growing of vegetables and melons, roots and tubers  Section A
#5     01140                                            Growing of sugar cane  Section A
#6     01150                                               Growing of tobacco  Section A
#...
```

I move all the `Code` that have `"Section"` in it in different column and `fill` the missing values.